# How does the youtube iphone app work

Tags: iphone, youtube

I want to make a youtube app like application for the iphone, where some videos are streamed/downloaded from a video site. But just by looking at the youtube app, I have a doubt.

I searched around on google, and it seems iphone does not have builtin support to play flv files. So how is the youtube app able to play the videos? Where does the encoding etc happen?

Comment: upvoted back to 0 as this was usefull for me

Answer (score 3):

From Wikipedia: "Since June 2007, YouTube's videos have been available for viewing on a range of Apple products. This required YouTube's content to be transcoded into Apple's preferred video standard, H.264, a process that took several months"

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone YouTube app doesn't play FLV, it plays H.264 versions of YouTube's videos. Apple arranged this with YouTube privately. You will need to convert your videos to a format that the iPhone can play.